# Apache: Address already in use

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4, httpd

Every time I try to start httpd on CentOS 7 on my Google VPS, the following message always appears. can you help me?

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-09-08 13:12:27 UTC; 1min 21s ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
man:apachectl(8)
Process: 2019 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 2018 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 2018 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server…
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web httpd[2018]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web kill[2019]: kill: cannot find process ""
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Sep 08 13:12:27 centos-web systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Comment: Use the formatting tools and write useful question titles "Problems on server" is entirely useless.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a server running on port 443. Check what other services you have running (e.g. `nginx`).

Comment: @seven How i do this?

Comment: with something like ```ss -alpnt | grep 443```, it will print service listening on port 443